# Prove that $A$ is semiprimitive

Tags: probability, matrices, matrix-calculus, stochastic-analysis, matrix-analysis

Matrix $A \ge 0$ is a semi primitive matrix, if for some $k$ matrix $A^{k}$ contains a positive column.

Prove, if characteristic polynomial of stochastic matrix $A$ equal to $t^{(n-1)}(t-1)$, then A is semi primitive and $\lim_{k \to \infty}A^{k} = A^{n-1}$.

Please give me some hints to prove it.
And sorry for my bad English. I'm not an English native speaker.

Comment: In your definition: do the *rows* of a stochastic matrix have a sum of $1$, or do the *columns* of a stochastic matrix have a sum of $1$?

Comment: The rows of a stochastic matrix have a sum of 1

Comment: See my latest edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Cayley Hamilton theorem, we have $A^{n} = A^{n-1}$. It follows that $A^{k} = A^{n-1}$ for all $k \geq n$, so it is clear that $\lim_{k \to \infty}A^k = A^{n-1}$.

As for proving that $A$ is primitive: first, show that $A^{n-1}$ must have a rank of $1$.

Now, note that $B = A^{n-1}$ is a non-negative, stochastic matrix with rank $1$. Because $B$ has rank $1$, we can write it in the form
$$
B = uv^T
$$
for column-vectors $u,v$.  Because $B$ is non-negative, both $u$ and $v$ must be non-negative. Because $B$ is stochastic, we can take $u$ to be the vector $(1,\dots,1)^T$. That is, the $i$th column of $B$ is equal to $(v_i,\dots,v_i)^T$.  Because $B \neq 0$, we must have $v \neq 0$. However, if the $i$th entry of $v$ is positive, then the $i$th column of $B$ must be positive.

Comment: sorry but how come characteristic polynomial of stochastic matrix A equal to $t^{(n−1})(t−1)$ then $A^{n-1}$ has a rank of 1?

Comment: @u There are a few way you can show it. One approach is to note that $\dim \ker(A - \lambda I)^n$ is equal to the algebraic multiplicty of $\lambda$. Another approach is note that every non-zero vector $y$ in the image of $A^{n-1}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with $\lambda = 1$.